# Privoxy and openvpn in docker

Tags: docker, openvpn, privoxy, raspberry

for one project purpose I want following. On rpi I want make proxy in docker. I install privoxy and openvpn in docker. When I start docker and start privoxy, everything works normally (I configure firefox to use privoxy on its port). When I connect openvpn client in docker, I can't get to privoxy anymore.

I'm starting docker with this command

```
docker run --name ubuntuvpn -v /openvpnconfig/:/openvpn -p 8000:8118 --device=/dev/net/tun --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it ubuntuvpn
```

What I suspect is that when I connect openvpn something happen with this device (--device=/dev/net/tun ) Maybe openvpn tunnels all traffic through vpn connection and don't listen on 8118 port anymore?

Can someone explain me in conceptual way what I'm missing?
(I found some container that do that but non of them work on rpi - arm7v )